# How to connect an android app to a node js server using socket.io?

Tags: java, android, node.js, typescript, socket.io

I'm trying to connect my android app to a nodeJS server using Socket.io 
this is the connection code from android:

```
final String URL = "http://192.168.0.103:3000";

try {
    mSocket = IO.socket(URL);
    mSocket.connect();
    mSocket.emit("message", "Hello");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Socket Connected!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

nothing more on android, also I have my internet permission added to manifest and I'm using next library:

```
implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0'
```

On the server-side, I'm using also Socket.io library, but for nodeJS and the connection is made like in following lines of code:

```
const app = express();
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
let http = require("http").Server(app);
let io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    next();
});

app.get("/", (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.send("hello world");
});

io.on("connection", function(socket: any) {
    console.log("a user connected");

    // whenever we receive a 'message' we log it out
    socket.on("message", function(message: any) {
        console.log(message);
    });
});

const server = http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("listening on *:3000");
});
```

When I'm trying to connect from android any line of code is executed with success, even the Toast message, but on server nothing. Also, I made a little script on nodeJS using `"socket.io-client"` library, for testing where I'm trying to connect to the same server and all the stuff is working fine, the connection is created with success, I receive the message on the terminal from the server, and from the script also I have a success message. the following script looks like this:

```
var io = require("socket.io-client");
function checkSocketIoConnect(url, timeout) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var errAlready = false;
        timeout = timeout || 5000;
        var socket = io(url, { reconnection: false, timeout: timeout });
        // success
        socket.on("connect", function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            resolve();
            socket.close();
        });
        // set our own timeout in case the socket ends some other way than what we are listening for
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            timer = null;
            error("local timeout");
        }, timeout);
        // common error handler
        function error(data) {
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = null;
            }
            if (!errAlready) {
                errAlready = true;
                reject(data);
                socket.disconnect();
            }
        }
        // errors
        socket.on("connect_error", error);
        socket.on("connect_timeout", error);
        socket.on("error", error);
        socket.on("disconnect", error);
    });
}
checkSocketIoConnect("http://192.168.0.103:3000").then(function () {
    // succeeded here
    console.log("working");
}, function (reason) {
    // failed here
    console.log("why not: ", reason);
});
```

Comment: Is the android device on your same network as the server via WiFi?  Are there error events you can listen to on Android to see what isn't working?  You need to be listening to and logging all possible error conditions on the client. Also, why are you only catching one particular exception.  You should be logging any exception.

Comment: I'm using an emulator and probably is on the same network